# Matlab method as a property

Tags: matlab, object, methods

Is there a way to write a Matlab class that has one of its own methods as a property? I'm writing simulation code in which the class's method (which is effectively a physics equation) might change in future development, so I'd like archived class instances to include the method.

Here's some Matlab-ish pseudocode.

```
classdef foo
   properties
      bar % some property
      baz % a property that contains the method baz
   end
   methods
       function out = baz() % the method I want to store
          stuff
       end
   end
end
```

Note that I want "stuff" to be somehow stored as a property so when I save an instance, I will know the version of the method I used.

It is preferable that it is public and also not a static property. I'd like to serialize instances.

Comment: You mean method _reference_ (i.e. function handle) in a property? Please provide some pseudocode (or code in another language) that shows what exactly you want to achieve and how to use it later on. I would also mention what sort of property and method attributes are desired (`private`, `static`, `const` etc.)

Comment: @Dev-iL I don't think I mean method reference. I would actually like to store the content of the method, not just its handle. I am new to using Matlab as an object-oriented language, and still an amateur at OOL programming in general, so my terminology might not be lacking. I'll try to write some pseudocode to explain more thoroughly.

Comment: I *could* add a property like "class version" and document things outside the class itself. However, there's a certain cleanness to having it self-contained.

Comment: So basically you want to save the class definition (or some part of it), in plain text, within some property of the class? I must say that this isn't something common in OOP.

Comment: Plain text is an option, but I think a function/method would be better. It's kind of bending the class back onto itself, I suppose. I'm trying to avoid pulling up an archived (serialized) instance created before a change in the method and naively using the contents of a property such as `simulation_results` without being able to check if the instance was generated from a class that shares the definition of a given method. I could use versioning, but this requires things to be tracked globally, not locally.

Comment: I suppose for simple "consistency checking," plain text saved as a property and compared to that of the current method isn't a terrible way to go. I suppose an extreme version of this would be to simply stash the entire class definition as a property ... how would that work? (Sorry, I'm sort of thinking aloud, here.)

Comment: @Rico you should remove this addition from the question and post it as an answer (since it appears to solve your problem rather than being a clarification for it). BTW, I think it might be worth it to write some function that accepts a filename and a function/method name and only returns the code of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Dev-iL's comment and Cris's answer, here's what I did, which stores the entire `classdef` file as plain text in the property `class_definition`.

```
classdef foo
   properties
      class_definition
   end
   methods
       function obj = foo()
         obj.class_definition = fileread([mfilename(),'.m']);
       end
       function out = baz() % the method I want to store
          stuff
       end
   end
end
```

As Dev-iL suggests, writing a function that accepts a filename and function/method handle and returns that function's code (as opposed to the entire `classdef` file) as plain text would probably better answer the original question, so I'll accept such an answer if it's posted. This solution was sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

If your function is a single expression, you can use an anonymous function. [It will be saved to a MAT-file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621) (Thanks to [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) for pointing this out). So for example:

```matlab
classdef foo
   properties
      bar = 0
      baz = @(x)sqrt(x)
   end
end
```

Now I can do:

```matlab
f = foo;
f.baz(2)  % returns 1.4142
save foo_test f
clear
```

And then change the definition of `baz` in `foo.m` to `baz = @(x)x.^2`, and then:

```matlab
f2 = foo;
f2.baz(2) % returns 4
load foo_test
f.baz(2)  % still returns 1.4142
f2.baz(2) % still returns 4
```

---

If you have more complex functions you could set it up this way:

```matlab
classdef foo
   properties
      bar = 5
      baz_func = @(obj,x) baz_2019_05_22(obj,x) % could be private
   end
   methods
      function out = baz(obj,x)
         out = obj.baz_func(obj,x);
      end
      function out = baz_2019_05_22(obj,x) % could be private
         out = obj.bar * sqrt(x);
      end
   end
end
```

And now:

```
f = foo;
f.baz(2) % returns 7.0711
save foo_test f
clear
```

In the future you'd change the function, but you preserve the code and create a new (private) function that does the computation:

```matlab
classdef foo
   properties
      bar = 5
      baz_func = @(obj,x) baz_2022_08_04(obj,x) % could be private
   end
   methods
      function out = baz(obj,x)
         out = obj.baz_func(obj,x);
      end
      function out = baz_2019_05_22(obj,x) % could be private
         out = obj.bar * sqrt(x);
      end
      function out = baz_2022_08_04(obj,x) % could be private
         out = obj.bar * x.^2;
      end
   end
end
```

The difficulty here is to preserve the old code without changing it... But you can make the `baz` function as complex as you want here. Now:

```
f2 = foo;
f2.baz(2) % returns 20
load foo_test
f.baz(2)  % still returns 7.0711
```

Comment: This is quite clever! It effectively serves my purposes, but it does require a vigilance in development -- if the deprecated method is removed, I believe your final statement `f.baz(2)` would throw an error (undefined method). All things considered, that's not a bad way to fail, though. However, if the method is changed without changing its name, we'd be back to not knowing about the old method, or even that there was one. +1, but I'll wait before accepting because another solution might still mitigate these limitations.

Comment: @Rico: Yes, you need to preserve the old code. Good programming practices need to be put in place, including a code revision tool to be able to go back to an older version of the code if things go sour. There is unfortunately no way to store functions in a MAT-file, except for anonymous functions which are limited to a single expression.

Comment: @Rico: Maybe there's a way to store an M-file as text in the object, and write it to file before calling it. This would not be performant, but it would likely be the most secure way to store code with your object. Maybe if I have time later I'll play around with this idea and post another answer. :)

Comment: Ha! You typed that last comment as I was spitballing something similar in the comments on the original question. I think there's something to be said for using such an approach, especially when doing scientific computing, for which reproducibility and transparency are virtues. Thanks for considering an additional answer :)

Comment: I believe I've implemented what we're discussing in my OP edit. I'll accept your answer anyway because it's most informative.

Comment: I changed the edit mentioned in my preceding comment to an answer based on Dev-iL's comment. Credit to you, @Cris Luengo, for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```matlab
classdef foo
    properties (Dependent, SetAccess = 'private')
        baz % a property that contains the method baz
    end
    methods
       function out = bazMethod() % the method I want to store
          stuff
       end

       function bazOut = get.baz(self)
           bazOut = bazMethod();
       end
    end

end
```

It won't serialize the current method definition bazMethod, but if what you want is simply the definition, it kind of sounds like what you want is for baz to be a Dependent property.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to serialize it ... is there a way to do this without making `baz` private? It's clever, what you've done ... close to what I need.